# Extract substring from complex html contained within curly braces and square brackets using regular expressions regex in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, regex

( I have updated this post to reflect a more accurate picture of the problem. This includes providing more info which I left out initially.)

Everything I have tried to get the desired strings results in an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

Here's my code:

```
image = re.search("photo: /\[[^\]]+\]/", text)        
image = image.group(1)
```

I'm still trying to learn `regex`, but this one has been throwing me for a loop for WAY too long.

I want to grab just the portion of the JSON that contains the photo link. That's everything that precedes the `"uploadTime"` excluding the `"id"`:

Here's the piece of JSON in question:

```
photo: [{
    "id": "http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418383-59832.jpg",
    "uploadTime": {
        "sec": 1498418386,
        "usec": 192000
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "md5": "6fac68fbcbdb31d17af7be277ab673be",
    "height": 600,
    "width": 800,
    "description": "",
    "originalFilePath": "",
    "originalFileName": "photo_0D993ADA-8AFC-4A79-8F9B-18E6F6C30B94.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418389-472609.jpg",
    "uploadTime": {
        "sec": 1498418392,
        "usec": 118000
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "md5": "6470e562d650099a1cafe9281f951c21",
    "height": 600,
    "width": 800,
    "description": "",
    "originalFilePath": "",
    "originalFileName": "photo_335B7BC0-F6DE-4E19-8489-3AA7B3920144.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418397-06491.jpg",
    "uploadTime": {
        "sec": 1498418400,
        "usec": 161000
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "md5": "5f2df3edfed164c062e739c0c3258970",
    "height": 600,
    "width": 800,
    "description": "",
    "originalFilePath": "",
    "originalFileName": "photo_9C57A971-9748-4DBD-919D-8D532C8D7C1A.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418403-391642.jpg",
    "uploadTime": {
        "sec": 1498418406,
        "usec": 936000
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "md5": "098dfa4d40e33c6897f62edc471670dd",
    "height": 600,
    "width": 800,
    "description": "",
    "originalFilePath": "",
    "originalFileName": "photo_A55BD209-3BFB-447E-AE59-40CF656664A8.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418409-263588.jpg",
    "uploadTime": {
        "sec": 1498418412,
        "usec": 789000
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "md5": "50b69c1db486f4bb6af723f7395a360b",
    "height": 600,
    "width": 800,
    "description": "",
    "originalFilePath": "",
    "originalFileName": "photo_8BCDC2F0-8CBA-442C-98F5-0389455C8014.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418415-54882.jpg",
    "uploadTime": {
        "sec": 1498418418,
        "usec": 462000
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "md5": "34296cda28b212a6c5590f233a2dca09",
    "height": 600,
    "width": 800,
    "description": "",
    "originalFilePath": "",
    "originalFileName": "photo_726D1636-E3A9-4515-9B95-55161FAAF730.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418421-389128.jpg",
    "uploadTime": {
        "sec": 1498418424,
        "usec": 518000
    },
    "extension": "jpg",
    "md5": "265087f19c17a99561a817f02a097b21",
    "height": 600,
    "width": 800,
    "description": "",
    "originalFilePath": "",
    "originalFileName": "photo_09B01A71-46F2-4D8F-9153-CE0F0017495A.jpg"
}]
```

This JSON piece is part of a larger string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var listingData = {};
      var userData = {};

      window.detailPage = window.detailPage || {};
                    window.detailPage.listingData = {
              id: 44782446,
              status: "Active",
              createTime: 1498418380,
              displayTime: 1500694902,
              expireTime: 1503286902,
              title: "Yamaha RX-V461",
              description: "Great Audio\/Video 5.1 surround receiver. Great condition ",
              city: "South Jordan",
              state: "UT",
              zip: 84095,
              contactName: "Robert",
              contactHomePhone: "801-635-6040",
              contactCellPhone: "801-635-6040",
              contactEmail: "hasEmail",
              lat: 40.5693,
              lon: -111.9672,
              latLon: "40.5693,-111.9672",
              price: 50,
              category: "Electronics",
              subCategory: "Home Audio Receivers",
              marketType: "Sale",
              sellerType: "Private",
              photo: [{"id":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418383-59832.jpg","uploadTime":{"sec":1498418386,"usec":192000},"extension":"jpg","md5":"6fac68fbcbdb31d17af7be277ab673be","height":600,"width":800,"description":"","originalFilePath":"","originalFileName":"photo_0D993ADA-8AFC-4A79-8F9B-18E6F6C30B94.jpg"},{"id":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418389-472609.jpg","uploadTime":{"sec":1498418392,"usec":118000},"extension":"jpg","md5":"6470e562d650099a1cafe9281f951c21","height":600,"width":800,"description":"","originalFilePath":"","originalFileName":"photo_335B7BC0-F6DE-4E19-8489-3AA7B3920144.jpg"},{"id":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418397-06491.jpg","uploadTime":{"sec":1498418400,"usec":161000},"extension":"jpg","md5":"5f2df3edfed164c062e739c0c3258970","height":600,"width":800,"description":"","originalFilePath":"","originalFileName":"photo_9C57A971-9748-4DBD-919D-8D532C8D7C1A.jpg"},{"id":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418403-391642.jpg","uploadTime":{"sec":1498418406,"usec":936000},"extension":"jpg","md5":"098dfa4d40e33c6897f62edc471670dd","height":600,"width":800,"description":"","originalFilePath":"","originalFileName":"photo_A55BD209-3BFB-447E-AE59-40CF656664A8.jpg"},{"id":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418409-263588.jpg","uploadTime":{"sec":1498418412,"usec":789000},"extension":"jpg","md5":"50b69c1db486f4bb6af723f7395a360b","height":600,"width":800,"description":"","originalFilePath":"","originalFileName":"photo_8BCDC2F0-8CBA-442C-98F5-0389455C8014.jpg"},{"id":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418415-54882.jpg","uploadTime":{"sec":1498418418,"usec":462000},"extension":"jpg","md5":"34296cda28b212a6c5590f233a2dca09","height":600,"width":800,"description":"","originalFilePath":"","originalFileName":"photo_726D1636-E3A9-4515-9B95-55161FAAF730.jpg"},{"id":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418421-389128.jpg","uploadTime":{"sec":1498418424,"usec":518000},"extension":"jpg","md5":"265087f19c17a99561a817f02a097b21","height":600,"width":800,"description":"","originalFilePath":"","originalFileName":"photo_09B01A71-46F2-4D8F-9153-CE0F0017495A.jpg"}],
              standardFeaturedDates: [],
              favorited: 1,
              pageViews: 68              };

          window.detailPage.sellerData = {
              sellerId: 1159545,
              sellerAccountAge: "Nov 2010",
              moreListingsFromSeller: [{"id":44782211,"displayTime":1500694907,"price":100,"title":"Moto Gear 3 Helmets and Alpine Star Tech 6 Boots S","photo":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498417151-456217.jpg"},{"id":44782400,"displayTime":1500694904,"price":30,"title":"Belts Pouch, Canteen Holsters For 2 Canteens","photo":"http:\/\/img.ksl.com\/mx\/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com\/1159545-1498418072-282620.jpg"}]              };

          window.detailPage.userData = {
              testUser: Boolean(0)
          };
                          </script>
```

How do I extract the piece I want?

Thanks for looking at my question!

Comment: Woah. This isn't html. This is json. And you should use a JSON parser.

Comment: Also you haven't specified which language you want a solution in.

Comment: Probably a fake account for the user @AlexR that posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257932/how-to-extract-string-from-complex-javascript-text-html-container-nested-in-betw) an hour before.

Comment: Not a fake account, I created an account for my girlfriend and asked from her account because I wasn't able edit my post or make a new post from my account. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for the tip COLDSPEED, I'm still pretty new to the scene here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you won't ask any more? And if this works you know you're meant to mark it accepted, eh?

That ugly thing can be viewed as a list of json 'parsables', if you will. I put it in a file that I could read into a script. Upon reading it in I knocked off the initial few characters and the final ']' leaving just the parsable items, minus their initial bits.

Then I did the splitting, not forgetting that the first piece from the split would not be used. Feeding each piece into the json parser yielded a dictionary from which could select the desired item.

```
>>> import json
>>> import re
>>> complete = open('temp.json').read()[6:-1]
>>> pieces = re.split(r',?\s*\{\s*"id"', complete)
>>> for piece in  pieces[1:]:
...     items = json.loads('{"id"'+piece)
...     items['id']
... 
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418383-59832.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418389-472609.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418397-06491.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418403-391642.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418409-263588.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418415-54882.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418421-389128.jpg'
```

EDIT: Changed problem. Very similar, except that it's a little more work to winkle out the line containing the desired information. That's the purpose of the additional `match` operation. Notice too that the previous line has changed.

```
>>> import json
>>> import re
>>> complete = open('temp.json').read()
>>> m = re.match(r'.*?photo:\s+\[([^]]+)]', complete, re.DOTALL)
>>> pieces = re.split(r',?\s*\{\s*"id"', m.groups(0)[0])
>>> for piece in pieces[1:]:
...     items = json.loads('{"id"'+piece)
...     items['id']
...     
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418383-59832.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418389-472609.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418397-06491.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418403-391642.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418409-263588.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418415-54882.jpg'
'http://img.ksl.com/mx/mplace-classifieds.ksl.com/1159545-1498418421-389128.jpg'
```

Comment: I don't appreciate the attitude, but I do appreciate your time and solution, thank you Bill. However, I haven't been able to reproduce the result on my machine because I didn't give you enough context into my code! (Doh!) The piece of code I provided is part of a larger piece of "javascript/text"; I have had trouble isolating the piece of JSON parsables I gave you guys.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect exactly what I'm struggling with.

Comment: No offence intended. I really don't care whether you were faking your identity or not. Can't resist teasing.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: You're the man, thanks Bill.

Comment: You're very welcome!